# Aligning to left and right inside a <td>

Tags: html, css

I am writing a page for role-playing with some friends. When it comes to the character sheet we would like to have some tables with the statistics. 
I would like to have inside every cell the name of the characteristic (strength, intelligence, etc.) and the number. Like this: http://jordi.dyndns-at-home.com:3000/characters/2

I would like to align the names to the left side of the cell and the numbers to the right side.

I have tried with <span style="text-align:right;"> and it will not work. 
I have tried with <div style="text-align:right;"> and it does work but it "jumps a line", if I use display:inline it will not work.

It is possible to have both alignments on a <td>  ?

BTW position:absolute; right:0 won't work. it will align to the end of the  not the end of the

Comment: isn't it easier to just put the names and numbers in their own td's?

Comment: Surely it is but I am not in a hurry and I'd like to learn while making that webpage.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use definition lists and be semantic.

HTML

```
<table><tr><td>
    <dl>
        <dt>Life:</dt>
        <dd>15</dd>
    </dl>
</td></tr></table>
```

CSS

```
dl {
    width: 200px;
}
dl dt {
    width: 160px;
    float: left;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
dl dd {
    width: 40px;
    float: left;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

This way you can drop the whole table.

Comment: But I don't think I can drop the table. I want that table look

Comment: @Jordi: give some border to the dl's (and adjust the width) then they would look like a table. Or better.

Answer (score 10):

Here is an example:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <span class='name'>name 1</span><span class='number'>100</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

With the following CSS:

```
.name{
    width: 200px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.number{
    width: 200px; 
    display: inline-block;  
    text-align: right;
}
```

Hope you find this helpful. Here is a jsFiddle for you to mess with.

http://jsfiddle.net/K4fGq/

Bob

Comment: OMG, the solution is good but jsfiddle is wonderful! Thanks a ton!

Comment: What if width is not static , if i want to give width in `%`  can i give it ?

Answer (score 0):

Although I agree with Oli's comment, I guess you can achieve it by using `float:left` and `float:right`.

Answer (score 0):

If you put another table inside the TD with two TD's, one left and one right aligned, it will work and I will get down voted for such a suggestion.

Another mechanism is to use display: inline-block as suggested by @rcravens -- my personal choice.